# What should i use instead of stmt.executeUpdate()?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

when I use stmt.executeUpdate() and if I use executeQuery it wont return the record I just inserted into the db i did set coccurency and type while creating the stmt object

my tables are

```
create Table Customer(
Customer_ID int,
Age int,
Contact_No varchar(20),
First_Name varchar(20),
Last_Name varchar(20),
PRIMARY KEY(Customer_ID)
);
```

and

```
create Table Customer_Address(
Customer_ID int,
Address_Line1 varchar(50),
Address_Line2 varchar(50),
City varchar(20),
Pincode int,
State varchar(25),
PRIMARY KEY(Customer_ID,Address_Line1)
);
```

My Java code:

```
try {

    st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    st.executeUpdate("insert into Customer values(Default,"+age+",'"+contact_no+"','"+first+"','"+last+"')");

    ResultSet set = st.executeQuery("select Customer_ID from Customer where First_Name = '"+first+"' and Last_Name ='"+last+"' and contact_no ='"+contact_no+")");
    int id = set.getInt(1);
    st.executeUpdate("insert into Customer_Address Values("+id+",'"+add1+"','"+add2+"','"+city+"',"+pincode+",'"+state+"')");
}
catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Screen1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: You should at least specify the columns that you are inserting into. i.e. insert into t_table(col1,col2)values(val1,val2)

Comment: Your insert values are out of order, and don't match the table definition.  You are inserting age into First_Name.....

Comment: Do your edits to this issue actually reflect your table schema?  I'm leaving

Comment: @Adam yeah mb i changed some stuff in db and that was the correct intended order my problem is once i do this the dbms(postgres) gives it an id by default i wanna get that id back but executequery wont give it back it throws a nullpointer exception at the Resultset set = st.executeQuery(""); line

Comment: You're missing an apostrophe here contact_no ='"+contact_no+"^^^^^^)");

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I don't think he's saying that.  The requery on the table after the insert isn't returning the row.. I suspect the row is failing to insert due to dodgy sql syntax

Comment: You need to call `next()` on your ResultSet object before using any of the `getXXX` methods

Comment: And I do hope you're sanitising those values before inserting them into an SQL statement like that!  Using a `PreparedStatement` would be advisable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the ID of the inserted row, use `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` like so:

```
st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO ...", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
int id;
try (ResultSet rs = st.getGeneratedKeys()) {
    rs.next();
    id = rs.getInt(1);
}

// ...
```

Comment: DAMN thank you so much :DDDD

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
ResultSet set = st.executeQuery("select Customer_ID from Customer where First_Name = '"+first+"' and last ='"+last+"' and contact_no ='"+contact_no+")");

ResultSet set = st.executeQuery("select Customer_ID from Customer where First_Name = '"+first+"' and last ='"+last+"' and contact_no ='"+contact_no+"')");
```